# Bootstrap integrated to Magento E-commerce. How?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, magento, integration, magento-1.9

I have question to people who had experience with Magento and Bootstrap. I was looking for some information how to integrate Bootstrap to Magento, but it did't helped me. I working right now on project that should be created on Bootstrap framework. So my questions is how to integrate bootstrap to magento right? So I can get bootstrap.css files that not mix with my own style.

I know that Boilerplate mix style with magento and code is too long, so I would happy to use it.

Comment: I think what you're after is "how to create my own magento theme"..   don't worry about bootstrap yet, just get the basics of how theming works in magento and you'll be able to add bootstrap to your own theme.

Comment: I know basics of theming with magento, but I have hard time to add some features to .phtml files. Because they are based on php. I am not well in php. However, I would look for more ways to make it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are flew blog available where explain the how bootstrap and magento integrated.

- https://www.packtpub.com/books/content/creating-responsive-magento-theme-bootstrap-3
- http://kimberelyt.com/magento-tutorials/day-1-creating-a-magento-reponsive-theme-with-twitter-bootstrap

You can try this

Comment: Thanks, but already got those links. However, I read all this websites again and found the book that shows me everything that I want.